# Summing and grouping in datatable

Tags: linq, datatable, grouping

[image: please see the picture fr my requirement]

1.Requirement:
the above is the result of my datatable value
1. Need to group the states by summing the premium value
2. need to mention the address, city  for the states which is having highesht premium values
3. Linq or for loop anything is fine for me, please help me out

thanks,
Srikanth Anantharaman

Comment: Result? What kind of result do you need, have you tried anything?

Comment: please see the result in the above image. thanks

Comment: @user2931394: that's an image, so you want an image as result?

Comment: @Tim: i have cropped and pasted my query as image instead of typing the same. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this LINQ query to fill a second table:

```
DataTable newTable = tbl.Clone(); // empty table, same schema
var groupedByState = tbl.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("State"));
foreach(var group in groupedByState)
{
    DataRow maxPremRow = group.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<int>("Premium")).First();
    DataRow newRow = newTable.Rows.Add();
    newRow.SetField("State", group.Key);
    newRow.SetField("Address", maxPremRow.Field<string>("Address"));
    newRow.SetField("City", maxPremRow.Field<string>("City"));
    newRow.SetField("Premium", group.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Premium")));
}
```